# Do all the so-called Satvik puranas agree as to the birth of Brahma?

Tags: vishnu, brahma, birth

Vishnu, Naradiya, Bhagavata, Garuda, Padma and Varaha is one list of "Satvik" Puranas.  Do they all say Brahma was born from Vishnu's navel?

Do any of the remaining Mahapuranas say that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story of the emergence of brahmaji is given as, in the waters of inundation only one lay, reposing on his serpent bed. When he desired to create, adopting the mode of Rajas, a lotus with the sun total of all of creation sprouts from his navel. It is in this lotus, that Brahmaji takes form and after praying to the one for creative powers begins his creation.

This story has been alluded to in almost all  of the 18 Puranas, as can be seen below:-

Brahma Purana:

> **From his umbilicus there grew up a lotus.** The quarters were its petals with which it was adorned. It had the refulgence of fire and the sun. It was embellished by the mountains that acted as the filaments. The winds were its blossoms. It was the excellent abode of Brahmā. **It was there that four-faced lord of Devas, Brahmā was born**. 
> -*[Chapter 71, verses 36-42](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216142.html)

Padma Purana:

> Invoke me for all divine missions”. In order to please Viṣṇu, who was speaking thus, Brahmā, the lord of the world of gods, thus praised him:”You created this world, **and the lotus issued from (your) navel. I was born there**, and am your servant, O Keśava. 
> -*[Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa, Chapter 4, verses 104-105](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364124.html)

Vishnu Purana:

> **Brahmā**, who is one with Nārāyaṇa, satiate with the demolition of the universe, who sleeps upon his serpent-bed—contemplated, **the lotus born**, by the ascetic inhabitants of the Janaloka. 
> -*[Amsha 1, Chapter 3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115938.html)

Shiva Purana:

> O sage, having deluded me with His illusion immediately, Śiva in the course of His sport, **produced me through the umbilical lotus of Viṣṇu**. 
>  -*Rudra-saṃhitā, Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa, [Chapter 7](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225975.html)*

Linga Purana:

> Henceforth you will be the lord of all; adorned with a white turban you will be **known as ‘padmayoni’[4] —one whose source of origin is a lotus**. O Brahmā, O lord, as son to me, you will be the overlord of seven worlds’ 
> *[Uttarabhaga, Chapter 20, verses 58](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-linga-purana/d/doc1195233.html)*

Garuda Purana:

> तस्य नाभेरभूत्पद्मं सौवर्णं भुवनाश्रयम् ।19 पद्माद्धिरण्मयाज्जातो ब्रह्मा तु चतुराननः।47
>
> From is navel sprouted a golden lotus that was the repository of the entire universe. From that golden **lotus, the four faced Brahma was born**. 
> -*Brahma Khanda, Chapter 11, verse as above*

Narada Purana:

> स देवः परमः शुद्धः सत्त्वदिगुणभेदतः। मूर्तित्रयं समापन्नः सृष्टिस्थित्यन्तकारणम्॥ योऽसौ ब्रह्मा जगत्कर्ता यन्नाभिकमलोद्भवः। स एवानन्दरुपात्मा तस्मान्नास्त्यपरो मुने॥
>
> That lord who is ever pure, took on 3 forms differentiated by the gunas beginning with sattva, that are the cause of creation, preservation and destruction. That which is the creator is called Brahma **who was born from the lotus that emerged from the navel**. He is the form of bliss and there is no one else other than him, oh muni. 
> -*Pūrvabhāga Prathamapāda Chapter 3*

Devi Purana:

> there came out of the wax of his ear the two Dānavas, Madhu and Kaiṭabha, of monstrous appearances. They wanted to kill **Brahmā, who was lying on the lotus coming out of the navel of Bhagavān**. 
> -*[Canto 10, Chapter 11, verses 3-9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57375.html)*

Agni Purana:

> Brahmā (was born) from **the lotus in the navel of Viṣṇu**. 
> -*[Chapter 5, verse 2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083093.html)*

Skanda purana (Khanda version):

> O Brahmā, leave off your impetuous turbulence. Indeed you swagger in vain. Understand that **you are born of the Lotus that has come out from my navel**.
> -*[Māheśvara-khaṇḍa, Arunācala-khaṇḍa (Uttarārdha), Chapter 9, verse 14](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370662.html)

Bhavishya Purana doesn’t have much information except stating the existence of the trimurti briefly.

Brahmavaivarta Purana:

> आविर्बभूव तत्पश्चात्कृष्णस्य नाभिपङ्कजात्। महातपस्वी वृद्धश्च कमण्डलुकरो वरः॥
>
> Then, **from the lotus that came from the navel of Krishna**, the great tapasvi, old and excellent one with a kamandalu in his hand was born. 
> -*Brahma Khanda, Chapter 3, verse 30*

Markandeya purana:

> Brahmā the Prajāpati **stood on the lotus that grew from Viṣṇu’s navel**; and seeing those two fierce Asuras and sleeping Janārdana…  
> *[Chapter 81](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117155.html)

In Vamana Purana, the creation story is not there, however in one Gajendra Stuti we have a reference to the navel and lotus:

> नाभिप्रजातकमलस्थचतुर्मखाय क्षीरोदकार्णवनिकेतयशोधराय। नानाविचित्रमुकुटाङ्गदभूषणाय सर्वेश्वराय वरदाय नमो वराय।
>
> ** he has the four faced Brahma situated on the lotus that sprouted from his navel**; has residence on Ksheera Sagara or the Ocean of Milk; he is multi ornamented on his various body parts; the provider of boons and the Emblem of Boons. 
> *[Chapter 85, verse 41](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/vamana/bookview.php?chapnum=19)*

Varaha Purana:

> Having created water and resting therein, I came to be called Narayana. In each kalpa, I again and again lie on water. And while sleeping there a lotus flower came out of the navel as now. **Then from the navel-lotus the four faced** came out. I ordered him to create. 
> *[Chapter 2, verses 12-13](https://ia902801.us.archive.org/4/items/dli.bengal.10689.12962/10689.12962.pdf)*

Kurma Purana (here during actual birth of Brahma, it is said he appeared. How, has not been explained, but a verse later calls him as lotus born):

> निवार्य च तदा रुद्रं ससर्ज कमलोद्भवः। स्थानाभिमानिनः सर्वान् गदतस्तान् निबोधत॥
>
> Stopping Rudra, the **lotus born Brahma** himself created the sthanabhimanis, hear as i enumerate them. 
> -*Chapter 7, verse 30*

Matsya purana doesn’t mention anything in the creation section except for the fact that Vishnu became the sun and the sun become Brahma. How when what why hasn’t been stated.

Brahmanda Purana (here there is defective text, but that matching exactly with Vayu purana can be recovered therefore, which says as under):

> Having passed the night-time in sleep, at the end of the night, creates god Brahmā for the creation of the universe. **He performs meditation on a (lotus) with golden petals** in order to reach the ideal state of Brahman. 
> -*[Prakriyā-pāda, Chapter 5, verse 6 and footnote](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc243176.html)*

Thus It can be seen that the story of the birth of Brahma from the lotus navel of Bhagavan has been spoken of in almost all Puranas, irrespective of their classification into sattva rajas or tamas.

Comment: So purana almost UNIFORMLY "demoted" Brahma from the supreme status he had in the Rig Veda "hiranyagarbhah samavartatagre". - very thorough answer. @Adiyarkku

Comment: Brahma isn't supreme even in the Brahma Purana ????????????? wow,  @Adiyarkku

Comment: @SK Hehe no. That’s the thing. Although some Puranas I’ve briefly read call Brahma as Hiranyagarbha, if you actually understand, then Hiranyagarbha is not Brahma. Rather it is the prakritik egg or the prakriti portion of ParaBrahman which lays in the golden egg. Hiranya=gold, garbha=foetus/ egg whatever. So when we see Hiranyagarbhah samavartatagre, it is essentially saying that the golden egg/ prakriti portion of Parabrahman existed in the beginning.